# syntax error near unexpected token `<<<'

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a bash script, which runs correctly in my system:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2 (2016-04-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But I need it to work in a Redhat 7.2 chroot:

```
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2 (2016-04-08) x86_64 unknown
```

The same code executes correctly on the first one, but when running it on 7.2 first it doesn't recognize sed -i (just the -i argument). Commenting some lines y run into another problem:

```
bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<<<'
```

The thing is, that this script need to be executed in a remote machine with a debian 7.2 (that's why i'm testing it in a chroot with the same distro), so it's no solution to install modules/upgrades to make it runnable.

A sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash       
...
count=0                                                                                                                                     
while read line; do                                                                                                                         
    if echo "$line" | grep -q ')'                                                                                                           
    then                                                                                                                                    
        ((count++))                                                                                                                         
        comas=`grep -o "," <<< "$line" | wc -l`                                                                                             
        num=`grep -o "byRef" <<< "$line" | wc -l`  
...
sed -i 's/shortInteger/int/g' "test.h"
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Edit:
These are the commands that cause me trouble:

> comas=`grep -o "," <<< "$line" | wc -l`
>
> sed -i 's/shortInteger/int/g' "test.h"

Edit 2:

> GNU bash, version 2.05.8 --> "here string" (<<<) doesn't exist
>
> grep (GNU grep) 2.4.2 --> -o option doesn't exist
>
> GNU sed version 3.02 --> -i option doesn't exist

Comment: If you are pointing line numbers in your code for errors then you need to show the complete script, else it is useless.

Comment: @Inian The code is too long to be posted here, and I should change many words to mantain code privacy. In the sample i point out the two lines that throw the errors. I'm going to edit the post to stand them out.

Comment: Are you sure your chroot is a close resemblance of your target system? This looks like you're using something not really a bash and not really a sed, maybe a busybox or something?

Comment: I think that the chroot is a 7.2 of 10-12 years ago, but i'm not pretty sure.
It's old, and the bin and libs are outdated, but everything needs to run on it as it is.

Comment: The first line could be changed to: ```comas=`printf '%s' "$line" | grep -o "," | wc -l` ```. For the second: what are the versions of each sed (from your system and from the 7.2 chroot?

Comment: @sorontar Thank you very much, i'll try it.
System sed version: 4.2.2
7.2 version: 3.02

Comment: For the grep lines, better try `comas=$(echo "$line" | grep -c ",")` and `num=$(echo "$line" | grep -c "byRef")`. The -c option to grep is defined by POSIX, should work for older grep.

Comment: The older sed 3.02 manual doesn't seem to have the option `-i` (in place editing). You will need to use a temporal file. Try: `sed 's/shortInteger/int/g' "test.h" > test.temp.h; mv "test.temp.h" "test.h"`

Comment: @sorontar happens that `grep -c ","` command doesn't work as it counts lines, so i don't get the number of commas in a given string. The temporary file worked well, so thanks for that. Any other ideas for the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it with the following...

For the versions i have which i can't update:

sed solution

> sed 's/shortInteger/int/g' "test.h" > test.temp.h;
>
> mv "test.temp.h" "test.h"

This was pointed out by @sorontar. Thanks a lot!

To find special characters or substrings inside a string

> comas=$(echo "$line" | tr " " "\n" | grep -c ",")

According to my source files, there's a pattern so after any comma I have an space. So `tr " " "\n"` separates substrings between spaces making newlines, then I can use `grep -c ","` to count each line with a comma inside.

Comment: If you want to count commas, it's probably more direct to do `tr -dc , | wc -c`

Comment: @WilliamPursell thank you. this also works and is smarter